# Bot is not identifying intents while testing through emulator

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have created a bot that uses LUIS. I defined intents and utterances on my LUIS app and also configured LUIS URL in my node js code.

```
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(process.env.LUIS_MODEL_URL);
bot.recognizer(recognizer);
```

When I am testing using emulator, it is not finding intents, and returning default message.

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
    session.send('Sorry, I did not understand \'%s\'. Type \'help\' if you need assistance.', session.message.text);
}).set('storage', inMemoryStorage);
```

Comment: Can you share how you are constructing the LUIS_MODEL_URL?

Comment: LUIS_MODEL_URL=https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/<APP_ID>?subscription-key=<KEY> 
I am setting this key in .env file

It works fine when I am trying at home, but not working in office on intranet

Comment: And if you use your LUIS_MODEL_URL in browser, or other tool to invoke LUIS request outside of your bot, do you get correct response?

Comment: Just crossing t's and dotting i's: Are you including the LUIS AppId and subscription key? The LUIS_MODEL_URL I use looks like: const LuisModelUrl = 'https://' + luisAPIHostName + '/luis/v2.0/apps/' + luisAppId + '?subscription-key=' + luisAPIKey; where "luisAppId and luisAPIKey are assigned the respective env values.

Comment: A few more questions: What version of the emulator are you using, v3 or v4? Is webchat the only other channel you have tested? And, can you post your dialog code (for example, your greeting dialog or similar) that you are expecting to be reached so I can test against it?

Comment: Yes I have used luis app id and suscription key. I am using emulator v3. 
bot.dialog('GreetingDialog',
    (session) => {
        session.send('You reached the Greeting intent. You said \'%s\'.', session.message.text);
        session.endDialog();
    }
).triggerAction({
    matches: 'Greeting'
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes... I got solution as well. I have configured proxy using global_tunnel with authentication 
**var globalTunnel = require('global-tunnel'); 
process.env.https_proxy = 'http://:@:'; globalTunnel.intialize();** 
Post **bot.recognizer(recognizer)**, I have added **globalTunnel.end()**;